# Authenticate user by permitAll

Tags: java, spring-security, basic-authentication

```
// @formatter:off
      httpSecurity
               .csrf().disable()
               .authorizeRequests()
                   .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET).permitAll()
                   .anyRequest().authenticated()
                   .and()
               .httpBasic()
                   .and()
               .exceptionHandling()
                   .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint());
      // @formatter:on
```

Why Spring Security authenticate the user for `GET` request when I set the Basic Auth (username and password) although all `GET` requests are permit without authentication?

For the username or password is wrong the `GET` request get an authentication error.

Comment: Why shouldn't it? You provide credentials, authentication is done before authorization, hence it will run first and as it is detected as a Basic Auth request it will be handled as such.